# VMWare vix api - not logging in into Vitual machine

Tags: c#, .net, vmware, vmware-player, vmware-tools

While powering up the virtual machine:

```
var virtualMachine = host.Open("myVM.vmx");
virtualMachine.PowerOn();
virtualMachine.LoginInGuest("Administrator", "myPass");
```

everything gets stuck in the log in screen of the VM. Is it possible somehow to start up the VM, and have the GUI loaded and ready, because automated tests require the GUI of the application to be present so the tests can fire off.

Answer (score 0):

pass VIX_LOGIN_IN_GUEST_REQUIRE_INTERACTIVE_ENVIRONMENT to LoginInGuest.

See the remarks: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix17_reference/lang/com/functions/RunProgramInGuest.html